# Swing JTable Layout: how to make table occupy complete viewport - like in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In the application I am building, I will be making a few tables display different data. And I want my table to look like the tables in **Eclipse IDE**, like in the **Problems View** or the **Tasks View** (ignore the tree structure of the Problems View)

What I am mainly interested in is the **last column** in the above views indicated in the picture below.

This column completely disappears when the table's width is more than or equal to that of the viewport. I have tried adding a dummy column with a blank header, but I can never make it disappear completely. Also even though the table is empty, it shows rows and cells. How do I get this effect?

Thanks in advance!

http://img329.imageshack.us/img329/7590/column.jpg

Comment: Check out [this](http://explodingpixels.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/creating-a-better-jtable/) blog post which describes exactly what you seek.

Comment: PERFECT - Exactly what I was looking for!! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use JTable's method `setAutoResizeMode` with one of the constants

AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS,

AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN,

AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN,

AUTO_RESIZE_OFF,

AUTO_RESIZE_SUBSEQUENT_COLUMNS